# Parameter expansion without colon (default value to empty string) in a condition

Tags: bash, zsh, parameter-expansion

I know the difference between `${var:-word}` and `${var-word}`, but I don't see the purpose of using a default value in [this condition](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/93990ab7da37007c8d9db16415cfb939aa5dd201/install.sh#L336):

```
[ -z "${NVM_PROFILE-}" ]
```

- Why is an empty default value needed there?
- Is it something related to compatibility with other shells (zsh)?

Comment: That code makes no sense to me. If the test succeeds, it goes ahead and uses a (potentially unset) `${NVM_PROFILE}` anyway. If the test doesn't succeed, it still uses `${NVM_PROFILE-}` in the `else` branch, even though `$NVM_PROFILE` must be set at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like `set -u`.

```
$ sh -c '[ -z "NVM_PROFILE" ] && echo empty'
empty
$ sh -c 'set -u; [ -z "$NVM_PROFILE" ] && echo empty'
sh: NVM_PROFILE: unbound variable
$ sh -c 'set -u; [ -z "${NVM_PROFILE-}" ] && echo empty'
empty
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `nounset` option is enabled with `set -u` or `set -o nounset`, `[ -z "$NVM_PROFILE" ]` would result in an error if `NVM_PROFILE` isn't set. Using `-` or `:-` to *explicitly* expand the unset variable to an empty string avoids that error.

An alternative to using `set -u` is to check explicitly if the variable is set. (This works in `zsh` and `bash`.)

```
[[ ! -v NVM_PROFILE || -z $NVM_PROFILE ]]
```